# How to query a post's custom fields of radio type

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am working with radio button for a list of colors. I am using ACF Advanced Custom Fields for creating the custom fields. I have no problem with other field types. I cannot get this to work because it's an array type.

I have 5 choices for colors - `red, blue, green, yellow, white.`

`<?php 
$colors = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fav_colors', true );
echo $colors;
?>`

The above prints `array` instead of the actual result. Also, `get_field` doesn't return any value so I resorted to using `get_post_meta`

How do I write and output the values of the radio fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check-in your ACF field where you created a radio button.

Select the `value` in `Return Value` and check once more. If the return value is `value` then you get the value like this.

```
$color = get_field('fav_colors');
echo $color;
```

If your site using caching plugins then purge the cache and try once more.

And if you have selected a `Return value` as Array then you can get that field like this.

```
$color = get_field('fav_colors');
echo $color['value'];
```